# How to change to color of the Command Prompt

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, command-prompt

I am running OS X El Capitan. Ever since I installed Ruby onto my MacBook Air the command prompt changed to `ruby-2.2.1` and it is colored green. I have looked at the color options in terminal preferences but have not found any that will change the color of `ruby-2.2.1` When I type `bash` into the terminal, it goes to `bash-3.2$` and it is white. This leads me to believe that `ruby-2.2.1` in green is some default setting somewhere. I would like to know how I can edit that default.

I am not asking about the IRB prompt. I am asking about the default prompt that pops up when logging into the terminal on the MacBook Air with OS X El Capitan.

Comment: You should have a look at your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` if you are using zsh you can define the coloration theme here.

Comment: Have a look in your `~/.irbrc` to see what settings are in there. Upgrading your Ruby might've added this customization.